# tikz: arrow tips |<->|

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to use a variant of `|<->|` in my draw command, but I want the tips to be the `stealth` arrow head.  Unfortunately, `|stealth-stealth|` isn't understood in the draw options command.

How can I have stealth arrow heads?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[|stealth-stealth|] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
  \draw[| stealth-stealth |] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work if you use: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[>=stealth]
    \draw[|<->|] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
    \draw[|<->|] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` ?

Comment: @PierPaolo yes but I used stealth instead of latex

Comment: It was a typo on my part, I later corrected the code. Does it work with `stealth`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tikz` version 3, you can do this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[|{Stealth}-{Stealth}|] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
  \draw[||{Stealth}-{Stealth}||] (0, 1) -- (1, 1);    %% || will produce thicker pipe
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]